# Rails display results from a through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So right now I'm displaying an TrainingEvents Index page that contains all events for every location. What I'm trying to do is create an TrainingEvents Index page just for that specific region.

My models look like:

```
class TrainingEvents
 belongs_to :location, optional: true

class Locations
 belongs_to :region, optional: true
 belongs_to :user, optional: true
 has_many :careers, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :training_events, dependent: :destroy

class Regions
 has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :careers, through: :locations
 has_many :training_events, through: :locations
 has_and_belongs_to_many :logos
 has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
```

My TrainingEventsController looks like:

```
class TrainingEventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html
  before_action :filter_time

  def index
    @events = TrainingEvent.by_month(@time.month).ascending
    @events = @events.by_state(params[:state]) if params[:state].present?
    @events = @events.by_city(params[:city]) if params[:city].present?
  end

  def show
    @event = TrainingEvent.find_by!(url_name: params[:id])
    add_breadcrumb 'Home', root_path
    add_breadcrumb 'Training & Events', training_events_path
    add_breadcrumb @event.name
  end

  def region_index
    @events = TrainingEvent.by_month(@time.month).ascending
  end

  private

  def filter_time
    @time = if params[:month].present?
              params[:month].to_datetime
            else
              Time.zone.now
            end
  end
end
```

The thought here was to create a separate method, region_index, to then pass along the new route. So in my Region's show page I have the following:

```
<%= link_to 'View Region', region_index_path(@region) %>
```

The link goes to the correct page but loading the data is where I'm stuck. Here's the view (in Slim):

```
= content_for :body do
  .container.banner-container
    .row.mt-4
      .col-sm-12
        = link_to 'Training Policies', '/training_policies', class: 'custom-button float-right'
    = form_tag :training_events, method: :get, id: 'filter-form' do
      .row.event-filter.align-items-center
        .col-lg-7.col-md-5
          = hidden_field_tag :month, params[:month]
          .month-selector
            = fa_icon 'chevron-left', data: { month: @time.last_month }
            h3 #{@time.strftime('%B %Y')}
            = fa_icon 'chevron-right', data: { month: @time.next_month }
        .col-lg-5.col-md-3.filter-select
          =link_to 'View All Trainings', training_events_path, class: 'custom-button float-right'
    - (@time.beginning_of_month.to_date..@time.end_of_month.to_date).each do |date|
      - events = @events.select { |event| event.time_start.to_date == date }
      - if events.count.positive?
        .row
          .col-sm-12
            .event-header
              span.date #{date.strftime('%d')}
              span #{date.strftime('%A')}
        - events.each do |event|
          .row.event-row
            .col-sm-8
              label.event-title #{event.name}
              .event-col-details
                - if event.time_start.present? && event.time_end.present?
                  = fa_icon 'clock-o'
                  p #{event.time_start.strftime('%l:%M %p')} - #{event.time_end.strftime('%l:%M %p')}
                - if event.street_address.present?
                  = fa_icon 'map-marker'
                  p #{event.street_address}
                - if event.city.present? && event.state.present?
                  = fa_icon 'map-marker'
                  p #{event.city}, #{event.state}
            .col-sm-4.details-cont
              = link_to 'view details', training_event_path(event.url_name)
          .row
            .col-sm-12
              .border
```

I know I need to hit @events.select and probably hit the locations then regions but I'm hitting my head on the wall. I've tried various methods of doing @events.locations.select, which gets a NoMethodError, or even an @events.regions.select, which gets the same.

So how do I pull in the through relationship and display only those results?

Edit:
I've also tried throwing into my TrainingEvents a scope thinking I might be able to query out the location id matching to the region.location_id with the following:

```
scope :region_index, -> {where(location_id: region.location_id)}
```

I end up with

> undefined local variable or method `region' for
>
> ## Did you mean?  relation

Answer (score 0):

region is not defined in your scope's context. I see you are already familiar with scopes using variables, looks like you only forgot that detail and needed fresh eyes.

```
scope :region_index, -> (region) { where(location_id: region.location_id)}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '|' :region_index, -> (region) { |region| where(location_id: reg ^. Haven't delved into what's up with this. Oh and I applied region_index under @events.region_index.select

Comment: True, I forgot that the `||` is not used in lambdas

Comment: More details here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1). Which I thought would mean that I need to pass something on the @events.region_index.select with something like @events.region_index(@region.id).select but it does not like that

Comment: `@region.id` is, I guess, an integer. I'm pretty sure it won't respond to `location_id`. You were right thinking that you have to pass something to `region_index`.  did you try `@events.region_index(@region).select` without the id? And `select` need arguments as well. Did you provide them?